# Count duplicate string in array(java) in existing code

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = {"java","c++","c++","java","c#","bootstrap","java"};
    Set<String> nonDuplicateSet = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> duplicateSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String abc:a){
        if(!nonDuplicateSet.contains(abc)){
            nonDuplicateSet.add(abc);
        }else{
            duplicateSet.add(abc);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(duplicateSet);
```

**How to count java is repeating 3 times/c++ is repeating 2 times**

Comment: Instead of using `Set`s, you could try using a `Map<String,Integer>`, where each `String` is stored along with the number of times it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
`String[] a = {"java","c++","c++","java","c#","bootstrap","java"};
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(String str :a){
            if(map.containsKey(str)){
                map.put(str, map.get(str)+1);
            }else{
                map.put(str, 1);
            }
        }`
```

and the for entrySet take the count.